# Powershell script not working as expected when publishing web app

Tags: c#, powershell, iis, gridview

The webapp works as expected when running within Web Developer but once its promoted to IIS; the problems start and the application does not run as expected.

aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="ResultGrid" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Uid,DesktopGroupName" OnRowDataBound="ResultGrid_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="ResultGrid_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ResultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserFullName" HeaderText="MUDID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BrokeringTime" HeaderText="SessionStart"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientName" HeaderText="Client"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DesktopGroupName" HeaderText="CTXApp" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SessionState" HeaderText="State"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Uid" HeaderText="Uid"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MachineName" HeaderText="CTXServer"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ENV" HeaderText="ENV"  />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Logoff" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Logoff" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to forcibly log off this session? Any unsaved work will be lost!')"
                                                        CommandName="Logoff" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Uid") + ";" +Eval("DesktopGroupName")%>'><img src="Images\logoffmin.png" alt="Logoff" /></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="Logoff"></HeaderStyle> <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Text;

namespace PowerShellExecution
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          // Gets the name if authenticated.
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    Label1.Text = User.Identity.Name;
                else
                    Label1.Text = "No user identity available.";

            // Clean the Result TextBox

            // Initialize PowerShell engine
            var shell = PowerShell.Create();

            // Add the script to the PowerShell object
            // shell.Commands.AddScript(Input.Text);
            // shell.Commands.AddScript("D:\\Local_Scripts\\sessioncall.ps1");
            //shell.Commands.AddCommand("c:\\Local_Scripts\\sessioncall.ps1");
            shell.Commands.AddCommand("e:\\wwwroot\\ctxrep2csharp\\Scripts\\sessioncall.ps1");

            // Add Params
            // shell.Commands.AddParameter(null,User.Identity.Name);
            // shell.Commands.AddParameter("Username", Label1.Text);
            shell.Commands.AddArgument(User.Identity.Name);

            // Execute the script
            var results = shell.Invoke();

            // display results, with BaseObject converted to string
            // Note : use |out-string for console-like output
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                // We use a string builder ton create our result text
                //var results2 = shell.Invoke();
                foreach (var psObject in results)
                {
                    // Convert the Base Object to a string and append it to the string builder.
                    // Add \r\n for line breaks
                    var UserFullName = (psObject.Members["UserFullName"]);
                    var BrokeringTime = (psObject.Members["BrokeringTime"]);
                    var ClientName = (psObject.Members["ClientName"]);
                    var DesktopGroupName = (psObject.Members["DesktopGroupName"]);
                    var SessionState = (psObject.Members["SessionState"]);
                    var Uid = (psObject.Members["Uid"]);
                    var MachineName = (psObject.Members["MachineName"]);
                    var ENV = (psObject.Members["ENV"]);
                    // builder.Append(psObject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
                }

                var objects = results.Select(
        r => new MyClass
                        {
                            UserFullName = (string)r.Properties["UserFullName"].Value,
                            BrokeringTime = (DateTime)r.Properties["BrokeringTime"].Value,
                            ClientName = (string)r.Properties["ClientName"].Value,
                            DesktopGroupName = (string)r.Properties["DesktopGroupName"].Value,
                            //SessionState = (SessionState)r.Properties["SessionState"].Value,
                            Uid = (Int64)r.Properties["Uid"].Value,
                            MachineName = (string)r.Properties["MachineName"].Value,
                            //ENV = (string)r.Properties["ENV"].Value,
                        }
                    );
                this.ResultGrid.DataSource = objects;
                this.ResultGrid.DataBind();
            }

            }

        protected void ResultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //Response.Write(ResultGrid.SelectedValue.ToString());

            //Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
        }


        protected void ResultGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //Get the value of column from the DataKeys using the RowIndex.
                //int uid = Convert.ToInt32(ResultGrid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0]);
                //string uid = ResultGrid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
                //string DesktopGroupName = ResultGrid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
            }
        }


        protected void ResultGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            //Response.Write(ResultGrid.SelectedValue.ToString());

            if (e.CommandName == "Logoff")
            {
                //Your code
                string[] arg = new string[2];
                arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
                Session["uid"] = Convert.ToInt32(arg[0]);
                Session["DesktopGroupName"] = arg[1];

                int numVal = -1;
                numVal = Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"]);
                Response.Write(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                Response.Write(arg[0].ToString() + "<br/>");
                Response.Write(arg[1].ToString() + "<br/>");
                Response.Write(Session["uid"] + " " + Session["DesktopGroupName"]);

                // Initialize PowerShell engine
                var shell2 = PowerShell.Create();

                // Add the script to the PowerShell object
                // shell.Commands.AddScript(Input.Text);
                 //shell2.Commands.AddCommand("C:\\Local_Scripts\\sessionkill.ps1");
                shell2.Commands.AddCommand("e:\\wwwroot\\ctxrep2csharp\\Scripts\\sessionkill.ps1");

                // Add Params
                // shell.Commands.AddParameter(null,User.Identity.Name);
                shell2.Commands.AddArgument(Convert.ToInt32(arg[0]));
                //shell2.Commands.AddArgument(Session["uid"]);
                //shell2.Commands.AddArgument(Session["uid"] + " " + Session["DesktopGroupName"]);

                // Execute the script

                var results = shell2.Invoke();

                //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "alert('your message');");

                //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + Session["uid"] + "');", true);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);

            }
            //Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
        }
    }



    internal class MyClass
    {
        public string UserFullName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BrokeringTime { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public string DesktopGroupName { get; set; }
        public SessionState SessionState { get; set; }
        public Int64 Uid { get; set; }
        public string MachineName { get; set; }
        public string ENV { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The webapp is in an application pool that runs as a domain service account in order the powershell code runs in the right user context. The page renders but the gridview results omits the first entries and then returns 2 duplicate rows of the last entry. However; what is odd if I restart IIS and quickly browse to the site it will render correctly but if I then refresh the page it goes back to showing duplicate entries in the gridview.

e.g.
Restart IIS and browse to page
[image]

On refresh and subsequent refreshes
[image]

I'm assuming its a context issue / IIS setting. Strange one.

Looks like it's an issue with the powershell code when adding to an array.

```
$SessionUser = "$($args[0])"
Add-PSSnapin cit* 
Set-brokersite -AdminAddress ukserver
$a = @(Get-BrokerSession -BrokeringUserName $SessionUser | Select-Object UserFullName, BrokeringTime, ClientName,DesktopGroupName, @{Name="SessionState";Expression={$_.SessionState.ToString()}}, uid, machinename,@{Name='ENV';Expression={'UK'.ToString()}})
#Pull US Sessions into array
Set-brokersite -AdminAddress usserver
$a += @(Get-BrokerSession -BrokeringUserName $SessionUser | Select-Object UserFullName, BrokeringTime, ClientName,DesktopGroupName, @{Name="SessionState";Expression={$_.SessionState.ToString()}}, uid, machinename,@{Name='ENV';Expression={'US'.ToString()}})

If ($a -ne $null){
    $a 
}
Else {
    $a
}
```

This works entirely as expected on the DEV box and happily enumerates all sessions into a single array. However; when promoting and running the code on the web server; it seemingly overwrites the first array call and a duplicate entry in the second array call?!

The only option is to run separate powershell scripts, which populate separate gridviews. It works but it's a bit clumsy.